# String issue when resizing image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I use below code to import an image from my Gallery to on my imageView. It is successful, but i want to resize the bitmap since app force close itself with heavy image imports.

```
String mPicPath1;
Button save;
ImageView logoview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);

mPicPath1 = null;

save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mPicPath1)) {
intent.putExtra("picture_path1", mPicPath1);
}

startActivity(intent);

}}
});

logoview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoview);
    logoview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    logoview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {            

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            openGallerylogo();
        }   
    }); 

private void openGallerylogo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) 
    {
        if (data != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) 
        {              

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mPicPath1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

logoview.setBackgroundResource(0);
logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicPath1));

}}  
  }
   }
```

When i implement:

```
mPicPath1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Then i need to change mPicPath1 is from String to Bitmap. If i change then i have "The method decodeFile(String) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments " error in this line:

```
logoview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPicPath1));
```

Can you please correct my code above to import big size images and can pass it to SecondActivity. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure something is put into `mPicPath1` and its not null?

Comment: You must use sampling of bitmap to make sure it will take less memory to load in memory.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn i didnt get your point. what im doing is to put a bitmap on an image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this :

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 2048;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

    int scale = 3;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);


}
```

And call this function as:

```
      decodeFile(mPicPath1 );
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use like in your code:
Make global **Bitmap** variable

```
  Bitmap  bmp ;

  decodeFile(mPicPath1);
  logoview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Thank you but how about bmp and filePath. Should i declare them above? And ExifUtils cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Umitk see my full answer

Answer (score 0):

Just go thorough with this to manage large bitmaps:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html